# How to fetch users who had at least 1 session within the last 5 mins in my Django app

Tags: python, django, performance

How can I use the Django auth system to show, in a Django template, all the registered users who had a session in my Django web app within the previous 5 mins? By "user", I mean a vanilla `django.contrib.auth` `user`. I'll access their usernames and populate a list showing all such recently seen users.

Since Django creates `HttpResponse` objects for each request sent by a `user`, I'm guessing there has to be a way to populate a *recently seen users* list? *Bonus:* performance is also key, so I'm open to ways of optimizing this request (it's a popular feature in my app, users' request "whose online" very frequently and every day during rush hour, request queuing tends to really deprecate performance).

**Background:** My app is meant for users in low-resource localities; it's built using *Django 1.5* and *Python 2.7*. most users use it over feature phones with **Opera Mini** as the default browser (this browser fetches all content through a proxy server and reformats web pages into a format more suitable for small screens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [django-user-sessions](https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions). This appears to provide the functionality you're looking for, then you could just do something like:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.utils import timezone
from user_sessions.models import Session


recent_users = Session.objects.filter(last_activity__gte=(timezone.now()-timedelta(minutes=5))).only('user').distinct('user')
```

That code sample is just off the cuff so I can't guarantee it will work, but it should give a nice starting point.

Comment: Yea I get what you mean. I'm going to try polishing it, and post my findings back to you. Thanks for chiming in :-)

Comment: This should be the easiest option; your other would be to write a request logging middleware, which would also work, but is a lot more work.

Comment: Can you comment on which could be the superior approach performance wise?

Comment: I'm not sure I can say for certain, as it comes entirely down to database performance at that point. Just at a guess, I would say that the django-user-sessions is likely going to be faster, as the table won't tend to grow as large... but that's purely a guess.

Comment: A separate question, if you're free to answer: each user is able to request "whose online". As stated in my question, during rush hour, I get a ton of request queuing because of this (currently I'm using django-request to do this currently). What if I moved the whole thing to a cron job, that ran every 2 mins, and updated the "whose online" list periodically for all users. Sounds more efficient, no? And my users come to my website for casual conversation, so its not too big a usability compromise).

Comment: I wouldn't even go that far. Just use the Django per-view cache: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache

Comment: And just to confirm: per-view caching caches the results webside-wide for all users, for the given time window (who hit a certain URL). OR, does this solely cache results for the one user who requested the view (in which case, a cron job would be more efficient in certain cases).

Comment: The per-view cache is a global cache, unless you explicitly tell it to vary per user

Comment: The snippet you pasted works fine, I've cross checked it. But it ends up showing me session data for only the *user currently logged in*. Anything from the top of your head to diagnose this behavior? I'm trying everything to get this to work.